# React Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autosuggest

React_autosuggestion did not show suggestions while typing on input box
even though the same code is copy pasted from documentation react-autosuggestion upi.

```
<ReactAutocomplete
    items={[
    { id: 'foo', label: 'foo' },
    { id: 'bar', label: 'bar' },
    { id: 'baz', label: 'baz' },
    ]}
    shouldItemRender={(item, value) => item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1}
    getItemValue={item => item.label}
    renderItem={(item, highlighted) =>
    <div
        key={item.id}
        style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? '#eee' : 'transparent'}} >
        {item.label}
    </div>
    }
    value={value}
    onChange={e => setCurrentValue( e.target.value )}
    onSelect={value => setCurrentValue( value )}
  />
```

imported as:

```
import ReactAutocomplete from  'react-autocomplete';
```

and the value is declared and set using a function:

```
const [value,setValue]=useState('');

const setCurrentValue=(value)=>{
 console.log('hhhh',value)
 setValue(value);
}
```

However, as shown in the screenshot below, the suggestion is not displayed.

[image]

Comment: I've solved it by correcting the onChange callback, can you double check your onChange callback. Would be good to analyse if you post your complete code.